# How to display one mysql row in another page, using form input and save this display in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

i got a table "categories" who got all my categories, in admin.php the admin can choose which category he want to display in index.php with a form and radio inputs.

**table "categories"**

```
category_id | category_name
    1           autumn
    2           winter
```

**index.php**

```php
<div>
    <h2><?= $category['category_name'] ?> new Collection !</h2>
    <a href="products.php?sort=<?= $category['category_name'] ?>">Show more</a>
</div>
```

**admin.php**

```php
$pdo = \Database::getPdo();



if($_POST){
    $category_choice = $_POST['category_choice'];
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = ?");
    $query->bindParam(1, $category_choice);
    $query->execute();
    $selected_category = $query->fetch();
}

$query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM categories");
$categories = $query->fetchAll();

<section class="change-news">
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
            <input type="radio" name="category_choice" id="<?= $category['category_id'] ?>" value="<?= $category['category_id'] ?>"><?= $category['title'] ?><br>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

What can i do for the admin choice to be permanent ?

I was thinking of creating another sql column named "selected" where i delete or update according to the input radio choice.

Comment: Can you define what "permanent" means to you?

Comment: You can save your data in $_SESSION too! it will be available in all pages

Comment: I don't see `$id` being populated nor `$selected_category` being used.

Comment: example: if he choose winter, there will always be the winter category posted until he choose another category. The visitors will see the category choosen by the admin. I think i need this "selected" sql column..

Comment: @chrstnsz It is better to create a new column in your table with boolean data type

Comment: You need a separate table to store Settings. When he selects the category it saves it to the database. When he views the main page it gets the category from the database.